# How to run custom maven goal inside Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

When deploy, my command line "mvn tomcat7:deploy" instead of just "mvn deploy", is there a way to let the Maven Projects view to run the desired command line when I click deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you double click on `deploy` in the "Maven Projects" view, it will not launch any application server, but [deploy maven artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) on a remote server (for example a Nexus instance).

If the tomcat maven plugin is [correctly configured](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html) in your `pom.xml`, you should expand the `Plugins` node under your Maven module (still in the "Maven Projects" view), expand the `tomcat7` node then double click the `tomcat7:deploy` goal.

As a second option, you could also create a new `Maven` run/debug configuration and specify your own goals, this is very useful if you have to provide additional parameters such as `-PmyProfile`.